# Can i declare TOP to pull the value from another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am looking to gather the TOP diff from the inventory table, where the newcount <> quantity.
Basically, if my inventory count was different than it should have been, I want to search my remaining inventory for the TOP # of missing parts. This brings me back an instock id to ensure that I am removing the oldest parts first.
I could have 900 of these, so I am looking for a sql command that returns the results from partsremainingfifo based on the diff and partnumber in inventory.

```
select 
    PartNumber, 
    Quantity, 
    NewCount, 
    diff
from Inventory
where NewCount <> Quantity

+------------+----------+----------+------+
| PartNumber | Quantity | NewCount | diff |
+------------+----------+----------+------+
|    2871451 |        1 |        0 |    1 |
|    4932615 |        6 |        1 |    5 |
+------------+----------+----------+------+


select top 1 
    id, PartNumber, 
    PartDescription, 
    Quantity, 
    TotalPrice,
    Brand, 
    Location, 
    Account
from PARTSREMAININGFIFO
where PartNumber = '2871451'


+------+------------+-------------------+----------+------------+---------+----------+----------+
|  id  | PartNumber |  PartDescription  | Quantity | TotalPrice |  Brand  | Location | Account  |
+------+------------+-------------------+----------+------------+---------+----------+----------+
| 9183 |    2871451 | AFM DEVICE GASKET |        1 |  19.815225 | CUMMINS | A1       | 6015-Z   |
+------+------------+-------------------+----------+------------+---------+----------+----------+




select top 5 
    id, 
    PartNumber, 
    PartDescription, 
    Quantity, 
    TotalPrice,
    Brand, 
    Location, 
     Account
from PARTSREMAININGFIFO
where PartNumber = '4932615'


+------+------------+-----------------+----------+------------+---------+----------+---------+
|  id  | PartNumber | PartDescription | Quantity | TotalPrice |  Brand  | Location | Account |
+------+------------+-----------------+----------+------------+---------+----------+---------+
| 3264 |    4932615 | GASKET          |        1 |   2.907144 | CUMMINS | A1       | 6015-Z  |
| 9780 |    4932615 | GASKET          |        1 |   5.053475 | CUMMINS | A1       | 6015-Z  |
| 9781 |    4932615 | GASKET          |        1 |   5.053475 | CUMMINS | A1       | 6015-Z  |
| 9782 |    4932615 | GASKET          |        1 |   5.053475 | CUMMINS | A1       | 6015-Z  |
| 9783 |    4932615 | GASKET          |        1 |   5.053475 | CUMMINS | A1       | 6015-Z  |
+------+------------+-----------------+----------+------------+---------+----------+---------+
```

Comment: What you really need is to provide some details. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ Also, remember that when using TOP you need to specify an order or you have no idea what rows you will get.

Comment: I am looking for something like this       select top (select inventory.diff from Inventory where inventory.diff IS NOT NULL) PARTSREMAININGFIFO.id, PARTSREMAININGFIFO.PartNumber, PARTSREMAININGFIFO.PartDescription, 
PARTSREMAININGFIFO.Quantity, PARTSREMAININGFIFO.TotalPrice, PARTSREMAININGFIFO.Brand, PARTSREMAININGFIFO.Location, PARTSREMAININGFIFO.Account
from PARTSREMAININGFIFO LEFT OUTER JOIN
inventory on partsremainingfifo.partnumber = inventory.partnumber
where inventory.diff <> 0

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments. If it is explaining your question you should edit your question as that information belongs in the question. And for heaven's sake, learn to use aliases. And please read the article I linked, just throwing queries at people is not going to get you an answer, it will just irritate people and they won't help.

Comment: See [mcve] for further details about what @SeanLange is talking about.

Comment: Agreed with @SeanLange about editing your question. It really helps especially since the comments section tends to cut off code, and has a character limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand what you want now, and I think you'll need a cursor. One important note, you **must** specify an `order by` when you use `TOP` unless you don't care *what* rows come back. [**Read this article.**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by/)

Here is how you'd implement this:

```
--create some sample data that you gave

declare @inventory table (  PartNumber int, 
                            Quantity int, 
                            NewCount int, 
                            diff int)

insert into @inventory
values
(2871451,1,0,1),
(4932615,6,1,5)

declare @PARTSREMAININGFIFO table ( id int, 
                                    PartNumber int, 
                                    PartDescription varchar(64), 
                                    Quantity int, 
                                    TotalPrice decimal (8,6), 
                                    brand varchar(64), 
                                    Location varchar(16), 
                                    Account varchar(64))

insert into @PARTSREMAININGFIFO
values

(9183,2871451,'AFM DEVICE GASKET',1,19.815225,'CUMMINS','A1','6015-Z'),
(9183,2871451,'AFM DEVICE GASKET',1,19.815225,'CUMMINS','A2','6015-Z'), --notice the extra (2nd) row here for part 2871451
(9183,2871451,'AFM DEVICE GASKET',1,19.815225,'CUMMINS','A3','6015-Z'), --notice the extra (3nd) row here for part 2871451

(3264,4932615,'GASKET',1,2.907144,'CUMMINS','A1','6015-Z'),
(9780,4932615,'GASKET',1,5.053475,'CUMMINS','A1','6015-Z'),
(9781,4932615,'GASKET',1,5.053475,'CUMMINS','A1','6015-Z'),
(9782,4932615,'GASKET',1,5.053475,'CUMMINS','A1','6015-Z'),
(9783,4932615,'GASKET',1,5.053475,'CUMMINS','A1','6015-Z'),
(9783,4932615,'GASKET',1,5.053475,'CUMMINS','A6','6015-Z')  --notice the 6th (extra) row here for part 4932615


--staging table for your results

declare @tempResults table (        id int, 
                                    PartNumber int, 
                                    PartDescription varchar(64), 
                                    Quantity int, 
                                    TotalPrice decimal (8,6), 
                                    brand varchar(64), 
                                    Location varchar(16), 
                                    Account varchar(64))



declare cur cursor local fast_forward for 
select distinct 
    PartNumber,
    diff 
from (select 
            PartNumber, 
            Quantity, 
            NewCount, 
            diff
        from @inventory
        where NewCount <> Quantity) x

declare @partNumber int
declare @diff int

open cur

fetch next from cur into @partNumber, @diff 

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    insert into @tempResults
    select top (@diff) 
        id, 
        PartNumber, 
        PartDescription, 
        Quantity, 
        TotalPrice,
        Brand, 
        Location, 
        Account
    from @PARTSREMAININGFIFO
    where PartNumber = @partNumber
    order by Quantity   --note you need to specify WHAT you want to order by 

    fetch next from cur into @partNumber, @diff 
end


select * 
from @tempResults
order by PartNumber

close cur
deallocate cur
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I need. Now since the table inventory already exists, and view PartsRemainingFIFO already exists how do I have this search inventory for any count discrepancies and then pull the sample data from the live database?

Comment: Well, I thought I found how to modify the search, but I get 0 results when I should have some

Comment: I did have to change the partnumber to PartNumber nvarchar. when I change that in the version with the test data,exactly as above, it crashes it as well giving this error Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type nvarchar.

Comment: Give it a length like varchar(4000)

Comment: I don’t understand  your other question because I can’t see your environment unfortunately. However I think this answer shows you how to do it, correct?

Comment: Yep, that was it. Great language on this and it does exactly what it is supposed to do. Thanks for seeing through some difficult explaination

Comment: No worries at all @BobbyKuhn